# Search for a specific letter in a specific spot within a varchar in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to search my database for any varchars with 'C' as the second letter.

I have tried   "like '%C%'"   but that returns values with C anywhere.

I am using mysql just in case that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_`, which is the single character wildcard.

For example:

```
select *
from your_table 
where your_column like '_C%'
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

```
select *
from yourTable
where instr('c', yourColumn)!=2;
```

the instr() function returns an integer which indicates the position of the first occurrence of the substring in the first argument within the string on the second argument.

Comment: Thanks! This seems more complex but I'll probably need it down the road.